# Django Like Syste --> RedirectView not redirecting to post

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-class-based-views

I ran into a problem while trying to figure out how to implement a liking system for my Django blog. I have a post Detail View and a PostRedirectView. I want the redirect view to get the absolute URL for the Post I look at and toggle a like/unlike as my liking system is a ManyToManyField linked in my models.py for the post. Here is the related code:

views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        comments_connected = Comment.objects.filter(post_connected=self.get_object()).order_by('-date_posted')
        data['comments'] = comments_connected
        data['form'] = NewCommentForm(instance=self.request.user)
        return data

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        new_comment = Comment(content=request.POST.get('content'),
                              author=self.request.user,
                              post_connected=self.get_object())
        new_comment.save()

        return self.get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)


class PostLikeRedirect(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs.get('id'))
        return obj.get_absolute_url()
```

urls.py

```
  path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
  path('post/<int:pk>/like', PostLikeRedirect.as_view(), name='post-like'),
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="users_who_authored")
    like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="users_who_liked")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.author} posts: {self.content[:8]}'

    @property
    def number_of_comments(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(post_connected=self).count()


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.author} posted'
```

The error I get is 404 page not found when I go to post/id(e.g. 2)/like and the error message

```
No Post matches the given query.
```

I know what the error means I just can not pinpoint the exact time and where I did not pass in the query correctly

Comment: Can you add the *complete error traceback*?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I did, that is the whole trackback Django gave me, and also those normal 3 lines at the top Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/2/like
Raised by: blog.views.PostLikeRedirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the **`id`** from the URL, but it was defined as **`pk`**. So, Change your view as

```
class PostLikeRedirect(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        return obj.get_absolute_url()
```